# Find the max height and width in a "island" map

Tags: c

I've been trying to do this exercise for a while but i cant seem to find where the problem may lie.

So the exercise goes like this:

We are given a matrix with 1's and 0's with 1 representing islands and 0 representing water
We have to build a code that finds us

1. The highest(more 1 in y direction)
2. The widest (more 1 in x direction)
3. The island with the biggest area

We also have to print the initial coordinates where this island starts(the first 2 are the dimensions of the matrix. the reading is done from a file)

```
5 6
1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 1
```

Here it should print:

Max height 3: coordinates(2,5)

Max width  2: coordinates(0,0) (in case there are many with same width we just print one of
them)

Max area   4:coordinates (1,2)

I have a basic idea on how to do it.

I tried to implement it but i cant seem to understand why its not working. For now im focusing on finding the max height and width. Im sorry in advance for the messy code(i'm a beginner so for now im more focused on solving the problem than making it look pretty)

This is what i have done so far

```
#include <stdio.h
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("file", "r");
    int n, m;
    int i, j;
    fscanf(file, "%d %d", &n, &m);
    int v[n][m];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &v[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Original Matrix:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", v[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    int maxheight = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int posx;
    int posy;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (i < n && j < m)
    {
        if (v[i][j] == 1)
        {
            height++;
            i++;
        }
        else if (v[i][j] != 1)
        {
            if (maxheight <= height)
            {
                maxheight = height;

                if (maxheight == height)
                {
                    posx = i;
                    posy = j;
                }
            }

            height = 0;
            i++;
        }

        if (i == n)
        {
            i = 0;
            j++;
            height = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("The biggest height =%d in position (%d ,%d)", maxheight, posx, posy);

    int width = 0;
    int maxwidth = 0;
    int posx1;
    int posy1;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (i < n && j < m)
    {
        if (v[i][j] == 1)
        {
            width++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (v[i][j] != 1)
        {
            if (maxwidth <= width)
            {
                maxwidth = width;

                if (maxwidth == width)
                {
                    posx1 = i;
                    posy1 = j;
                }
            }

            width = 0;
            j++;
        }

        if (j == m)
        {
            j = 0;
            i++;
            width = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe biggest width =%d in position (%d ,%d)", maxwidth, posx1, posy1 - maxwidth);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are the islands always rectangles (or could you have [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqB89.png))?

Comment: I suppose that islands are always rectangle likes. in this exercise we dont have to worry about wierd shapes.

Comment: I'd code this as two nested loops (row and column) that search the map for a 1. When a 1 is found, check that the elements above and to the left are both 0 (or off the side of the map). That's how you know the 1 is the upper left corner of a rectangle. Then write two loops that determine the width and height of the rectangle.

Comment: Severjan Lici, what results do you see?  "not working" is insufficient.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I mean that im getting the wrong conclusion

Comment: SeverjanLici, what was the wrong  conclusion  that was printed out when you ran your code?  Please report your code's output.  Best to append that output to the question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i cant seem to update the page for some reason. is it all right if i post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the vertical max tests.
In the entire map was `1`, codes reports the `maxheight` as 0.

Code needs to assess `maxheight<=height` after every `height++;`, not in the `if(v[i][j]!=1)` block.

Likewise for `width`.

Comment: Like my thought process was like this. We keep searching in the height case vertically untill we find a 1. The moment we find a 1 we add to the height so height++. The moment we find something that isnt 1 we do the comparison. If maxheight> height. and if so we add this value to the maxheight. do you mean to say that each time we find a continuous 1 we update the value of maxheight ?

Comment: Yes.  Error in your algorithm: "The moment we find something that isnt 1" should be "The moment we find something that isn't 1 _or are at the last row_."  Checking after each `height++` is easier.

Comment: so i should include a i==n at the end is this what you mean?

Comment: No.  I suggest checking after each `height++`.

Comment: yep. it worked.  Thanks for the help